# Changing text on button in multiple items (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to using React. I have a series of data in which there is a button in every item and by clicking it the text of a special div must be changed, but the issue is that on clicking the button of one item, the text of the div in all items is changed. I want that when I click the button, the text of the div which is in the respected item should change.The main problem is that when second item clicked the first item text will disappear and the text of second one is the text of first one.Thank you in advance.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        num: 0,
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/json.bc",
        type: "get",
        success: (result) => {
            this.setState({ data: eval(result) });
        }
    })
}
renderFlight() {
    return this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <div class="item">
                <div class="btn" onClick={((e) => this.rueldep(e, item, i))}>click</div>
                <div class="text">
                    {(this.state.num == i + 1) ? this.state.rueldepTxt : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
rueldep = (e, item, index) => {
    var desc = item.info.departureinformation.routeshow.description
    return this.setState({
        rueldepTxt: desc,
        num: index + 1
    });
};
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.renderFlight()}</div>
    )
} 
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'));
```

Comment: You don't need to return anything in map. return this.state.data.map((item,i)=>{
return(    Remove the second return bracket

Comment: Hi  Nagesh Katna.I didn't get what you mean. I should remove (e,item,i) in this.rueldep(e,item,i) ??

Comment: So what would be the difference in not using it?

Comment: No, I mean that you have two return statements in your renderFlight() function. The second return statement is not needed.

Comment: Can you give an example of what kind of data are you receiving in your state 'data'

Comment: Ok, but if i removed, it won't work , the result doesn't show in Result div. On the other hand doing this will solve the problem?

Comment: I need to get an example of you data you are recieving and trying to display.

Comment: [{'_id': '5bebdc61e1382343fbd8e328',total': 40680000},

Comment: {'_id': {'value': 'eydGYXJlU291cmNlQ29kZSc6ICczNzM1NjUzNDY0Mzc2MjM1MzQzMDMxMzEzNDYxNjU2MzM4MzIzNzMwMzg2MjY0NjYzNzM3MzQzODM1MzI2NjMwMjYzNjM3MjYzMzMzMzAzNzMyMzgzOTM2JywgJ3Byb3ZpZGVyJzogeydwcm92aWRlcl9pZCc6ICczJywgJ2RtbmlkJzogMzk4MS4wfSwgJ2ZhcmV0eXBlJzogMn0=', 'provider': {'provider_id': '3', 'dmnid': '3981-0'}, 'fareType': 2},total': 50680000,}]

Comment: The data is a json containing of an array with some objects in it.